# Prime symbol in Python variable name

Tags: python, variables, unicode

So I'm a terrible person and I want to name a variable in my mathy-python3 code `s′` (that's [U+2032 PRIME](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2032/index.htm)).

I was under the impression Unicode literals work as identifiers in Python 3, which is why my `ɣ`, `α`, and `ε`'s are working fine.

Is the prime symbol specifically forbidden because of how terrible it would be to use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot just use *any* Unicode character in Python identifiers. There *are* [rules governing what can be used](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers):

> ```
> identifier   ::=  xid_start xid_continue*
> id_start     ::=  <all characters in general categories Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, Lo, Nl, the underscore, and characters with the Other_ID_Start property>
> id_continue  ::=  <all characters in id_start, plus characters in the categories Mn, Mc, Nd, Pc and others with the Other_ID_Continue property>
> xid_start    ::=  <all characters in id_start whose NFKC normalization is in "id_start xid_continue*">
> xid_continue ::=  <all characters in id_continue whose NFKC normalization is in "id_continue*">
> ```
>
> The Unicode category codes mentioned above stand for:
>
> [Lu - uppercase letters](http://codepoints.net/search?gc=Lu)
> [Ll - lowercase letters](http://codepoints.net/search?gc=Ll)
> [Lt - titlecase letters](http://codepoints.net/search?gc=Lt)
> [Lm - modifier letters](http://codepoints.net/search?gc=Lm)
> [Lo - other letters](http://codepoints.net/search?gc=Lo)
> [Nl - letter numbers](http://codepoints.net/search?gc=Nl)
> [Mn - nonspacing marks](http://codepoints.net/search?gc=Mn)
> [Mc - spacing combining marks](http://codepoints.net/search?gc=Mc)
> [Nd - decimal numbers](http://codepoints.net/search?gc=Pd)
> [Pc - connector punctuations](http://codepoints.net/search?gc=Pc)
> [Other_ID_Start](http://codepoints.net/search?OIDS=1) - explicit list of characters in PropList.txt to support backwards compatibility
> [Other_ID_Continue](http://codepoints.net/search?OIDC=1) - likewise

The above is the Unicode equivalent to *any number of letters, digits and underscores, as long as you don't **start** with a digit*.

The [U+2032 PRIME codepoint](http://codepoints.net/U+2032) doesn't fall in any of those classes; it is considered [Po - other punctuation](http://codepoints.net/search?gc=Po) instead.

I've linked the Unicode categories to codepoint.net queries for you so you can see what kind of characters *are* permitted. Your other identifier choices are all *Ll lowercase letter* characters, by the way.

You do want to be careful and use some common sense in what you use as identifiers. Keep them *readable* and *recognisable*. Preferably they should be easy to type too, so personally I'd steer away from using greek lowercase letters myself. I'd rather use `alpha`, `gamma`, `epsilon` and `s_prime` instead here.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* use U+02BC MODIFIER LETTER APOSTROPHE: `ʼ`.

```
aʼ = "ok"
print(aʼ)
```

... prints `"ok"`.

*Should* you use it in Python 3? As others have said, certainly not. But coming from an OCaml background, I must confess U+0027 APOSTROPHE (`'`) in identifiers is quite useful, especially for mathy-code.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a single-quote character, which is probably what most programmers would simply assume, unless you told them, or they squinted and looked really close. Heck, there could be fonts that use the same glyph for both characters. Even if you *can* use it, I'd avoid it, to avoid the possible confusion it might cause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Modifier letter prime" (U+02B9) and "Modifier letter double prime" (U+02BA) as part of a Python identifier.

Mapping AltGr+' and AltGr+" to prime and double prime make them easily available.

Some monospaced fonts do a good job in distinguishing them from single and double quotes, others are not so good (see screenshot – prime on the left, quotes on the right).

[image: prime (left) and quotes (right) symbols rendered with some monospaced fonts]